# Unable to load pdf from url using Syncfusion_flutter_pdf

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I am working on an application that requires me to load pdf from url. The plugin I am using is syncfusion_flutter_pdf. I couldn't find a direct way to do the same so I tried downloading the file first and then use it. But the pdf is not displaying for some reason! There were nothing in the logs. Can you guys please tell me what went wrong?

```
fileDownload() async {
    tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    tempPath = tempDir.path + 'flutter-succinctly.pdf';
    final dio = Dio();

    if (await File(tempPath).exists()) {
      //print('tempPath exists at: $tempPath');
      if (await File(tempPath).length() == 0) {
        dio.download(
          'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
          tempPath,
        );
      } else {
        _readPDF();
      }
    } else {
      print('path does not exist');
      dio.download(
          'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
          tempPath);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _readPDF() async {
    final PdfDocument document =
        PdfDocument(inputBytes: File(tempPath).readAsBytesSync());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Generate PDF'),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
              onSurface: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: fileDownload,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not have direct support to load PDF from URL. We can load and read PDF data by using http package. We have created a sample to read the PDF data from webspace/website to load and save it using the retrieved PDF data. Kindly try the following code example and sample in your side,

1. Add http package in dependencies section of pubspec.yaml file

   dependencies:
   http: ^0.13.3
2. Import the following package in your dart file.

   //Read an PDF data from website/webspace
   import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
3. Get image data

   //Read an PDF data from website/webspace
   var url = "https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf";
   var response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
   var data = response.bodyBytes;
4. Load data into PDF document

   //Create a new PDF document
   PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(inputBytes: data);
   //Save PDF document
   final List bytes = document.save();
   //Dispose the document.
   document.dispose();

Please find the sample from https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/pdf_sample565926150.